# User asking bad questions over a long period of time, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, moderation

I've come across a user asking very broad vague questions over a long period of time. Somehow they seem to have slipped through the net and don't have many close votes or even downvotes. I've added a lot of close votes to some of their questions and pointed them at help pages in their most recent post.

What's the appropriate action here?

I've add a lot of close votes (possibly a dozen but it could need more). Is this going to be flagged as serial voting?

I'd like to downvote a lot of them but again I'm worried about getting myself a serial voting flag. To clarify I have no axe to grind with this person they are just spamming the site with bad questions.

Should I flag this to a mod?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yeah, there are a number of users who have been asking so many questions on the site for so long, with some of their questions striking the views/votes/badges lottery, that they're basically completely immune to question bans and can therefore get away with repeatedly asking bad questions with no motivation to improve.

We have a moderator message designed for users with a pattern of asking low quality questions that we can use to address these users. If they don't show signs of improvement, we can issue a suspension. I would definitely recommend notifying us about these users, since they won't be affected by question bans. You can say something along the lines of:

> User has a long history of asking bad or off-topic questions and doesn't appear to be question banned despite most of them being downvoted and/or closed. Might need a talking-to.

Bonus points if you can highlight specific patterns, e.g. questions are mostly requirement dumps, mostly incoherent, etc. (The call-to-action is mostly a pleasantry and probably not actually *needed*; I think we're smart enough to figure out what to do.)

The same advice about not going through their profiles and voting on their questions applies. However, if the questions they're constantly asking are indeed bad, you don't have to worry even if you're downvoting and voting to close their questions on sight, because chances are you're not the only one doing so. I've seen users with very poor track records, having received downvotes from significantly more users than upvotes over the years — and *very* few of these downvotes originate from voting rings orchestrated specifically to attack them. It's easy to tell that the downvotes they received were largely organic and because their questions are just that low quality.

Use your best judgement when voting, and trust that we will use ours as well.

Comment: Great thanks. I've rasied a flag and will now move on with my life! :)

Comment: When you say _"we can issue a suspension"_ are you talking about suspension like when the user have 1 rep and a notice on their profile page, or a standard question ban?

Comment: @Alon Eitan: The former; the notice will say "This account is temporarily suspended because of low-quality contributions." Question bans are entirely automated and we have no control over them. This does imply that a user will be completely prevented from posting, voting, or editing, but we don't have any alternatives.

Comment: Can you give us a specific wording for moderation flags for this specific case of users that will not be interpreted in a negative way?

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Non action is a form of action too. If no one responds to their bad posts, eventually they will not see the worth of using the Stack sites and move along somewhere else.

Comment: @Kode as we know, SO is all about everyone making rational decisions to improve net happiness in the long run :|