# Multiple bad questions in short time span - can I downvote them all?

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

A certain user has posted three questions in a period of five hours on a tag I visit a lot, and they all show virtually no research or code debugging skills.

I'd like to downvote all these questions, but I fear that my votes will get reverted.

I haven't scanned his profile or anything and would've downvoted them all if they were from different users.

I've read *[Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting)*, and believe the votes are legitimate, but the answers there don't discuss possible reversion of the votes. I've currently only downvoted the worst one.

Comment: 3 questions in a period of 5 hours is suspicious anyway.

Comment: Oded's answer leaves nothing to the imagination.  That you don't like the answer has never been a good reason to just ask the question again.

Comment: @HansPassant Oded answers to someone who has visited a specific profile, and downvotes questions of that specific user. I am just following a tag, and voting on questions that come along. That's a different case, and thus I believe that Oded's answer is not applicable to my situation. I'm not serial voting, I'm just voting on all questions that are on that specific tag (those 3 questions are all in the last 5 questions on that tag). And it just happens that 3 of them are bad and from the same user.

Comment: Why do *you* have to do all the downvoting though? Just donwvote the first couple of posts you encounter, so that you don't trigger the script, and let the rest of the community do the downvoting on the remaining posts. If they are that bad, someone with notice it...

Comment: @user000001 the tag I'm following has few active contributors, and questions rarely get more than 1-2 votes there (I'm the top answerer on the tag for the last months, and I probably cast a significant portion of all votes on that tag). If I don't vote, I doubt anyone else will

Comment: Maybe you ought to disclose that you answered the question you downvoted and only considered downvoting all of his recent questions after deleting your answer.  It is pretty relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I did do that. I scanned over the question, identified an issue, and quickly answered it. Then I identified multiple other issues in the code, and even after fixing all these I couldn't replicate the issue because the question was incomplete (hence: wanting to downvote). Yes, I should've read the question better and not answered it. Sorry for not disclosing it if you feel it is relevant. I was working top-down on the tag, but would've downvoted these other questions if they were from other users

Comment: Are we talking bad as in "The user did no work", or bad as in "The question is just terrible"?

Comment: @Machevity I think both. The one I answered contains code with numerous issues, but not enough information to answer it. The other two are answered, one within 2 minutes because the error was really obvious, the other took slightly longer. All have little value for future users in my opinion, even if asked properly with research.

Comment: If you believed that the question deserves a downvote I don't understand why you thought it was worth answering in its current state. If you think the question is salvageable, and that your answer may help the OP & future readers, you should fix the question, or better still, help the OP to fix it, before submitting an answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring As said, I regret answering that question. I thought the first bug I saw in the code probably answered the question, but upon further investigation, there were more to be found, and even after fixing all of them, the question was incomplete and the actual error was not reproducible with the provided information. Someone already commented, asking for further information to reproduce the problem, but has thus far been unanswered.

Comment: to quote [boltclock here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352235/542251) *Use your best judgement when voting, and trust that we will use ours as well.*

Comment: My post on [the legitimacy of serial close-voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348135/should-we-refrain-completely-from-close-voting-by-user) may be useful. I think the essence is that it is thought to be OK to close several questions for the same user, as long as you are giving each one a fair go, and you are not looking to punish the user unfairly.

Comment: Shog9 once told me [this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6367845#6367845), conclusion stop guessing what script does, if you vote in a natural way the script "should" not reverse and you are not at fault instead you are doing good!. If you find that the script reverse your natural vote post a meta and explain what has happen so they can improve it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If the same user is posting multiple bad questions, then the answer here is to vote to close them (which is why you have close votes). Closure, in my experience, helps stop the problem far more than downvotes. You can serial close vote to your heart's content (or you run out of close votes). Whether or not they wind up closed remains to be seen, but you can always ask your fellow users (like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)) to help get them closed as well (note that we don't target users, so you need to be able to explain how you found the multiple questions).

Beyond that, just downvote one a day. Trying to downvote two back-to-back may soon be caught as unnatural voting.

Comment: Doesn't closing the question make the user more likely to just ask a new question about the problem?

Comment: @Bergi You can then close it as a duplicate of the first. If it's particularly egregious, mod flag it. They don't view end-runs of moderation actions very well

Comment: I would think that egregious rapid-fire posting of bad questions might also be worth a mod flag.

Comment: What @jpmc26 said. Don't use moderator flags as an end-run around your own close-vote/flag privileges, but informing us that someone is literally abusing the site by continually re-asking the same question is a perfectly valid use of flags. Also, I disagree with the implication here that downvotes are somehow less effective than close votes. That's not true at all. Close votes don't contribute to automatic bans, while downvotes do. Downvotes are one of the most underrated quality enforcement mechanisms that exist on this website. There is no reason you can't use both, of course.

Comment: Also, the downvote reversal script might be stupid (or it might not be), and the votes might get invalidated, but if you're honestly voting in good faith, then it's exceptionally unlikely that a moderator would ever seek to penalize you for it. We weren't born yesterday. We can see question histories, including deleted questions, and we know who the top users in a particular tag are. Lots of this was mentioned in the comments above (*i.e.*, in Liam's and Petter's), but I'd like to see it more clearly stated in the accepted answer. This reads to me as far too discouraging against downvoting.

Comment: Note though, that successive close votes requests for the same user are not allowed on SOCVR (see the [faq](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-dont-target-users))

Comment: The whole premise of the question is that this is a very low populated tag with very few active users.  The OP is worried that there won't be more than at most one other person to vote on these questions.  If they're not able to get more than 2 downvotes, how would you expect such questions to get 5 close votes in order to actually get closed?